# Throw exception before filtering?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Before filtering the `items`, it will check if `removeId` exists in the `items` otherwise it will throw an exception. Is there a way to avoid having two loops? This code might be badly written for having two loops.

```js
const items = [
    { "Id": 111 },
    { "Id": 111 },
    { "Id": 222 },
    { "Id": 222 },
    { "Id": 333 },
    { "Id": 333 },
]

const removeId = 222;
const find = items.some(item => item.Id === removeId);

if (!find) {
    throw new Error(`Id not found: ${removeId} `);
}

const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.Id !== removeId);

console.log(filteredItems);
```

Comment: why do you want to throw an exception before the filtering?

Comment: Throw the error if `filteredItems` is the same length as `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to throw an error right away so as to avoid the `filter` part you will have to go through the array anyway. So, **you cannot avoid iterating through the array at least once.** You can check if the length of the filtered array and the original array is the same to see if an exception needs to be thrown and to do the filtering at the same time.

```js
const items = [
    { "Id": 111 },
    { "Id": 111 },
    { "Id": 222 },
    { "Id": 222 },
    { "Id": 333 },
    { "Id": 333 }
];

const removeId = 222;

const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.Id !== removeId);

if (filteredItems.length === items.length) {
    throw new Error(`Id not found: ${removeId} `);
}

console.log(filteredItems);
```

If you are still concerned about efficiency you could replace your `Array` method calls (i.e. `Array#filter`) with `for (;;)` loops.

### Update

In modern browsers, `Array` methods are just as efficient as `for` loops (info was brought into the light by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069353/throw-exception-before-filtering/58069701#102535914))

Comment: "*If you are still concerned about efficiency*" - then keep using `filter` because it has higher developer efficiency and the [same performance](https://youtu.be/m9cTaYI95Zc?t=951)

Comment: @Bergi Wan't aware of that development. Is that the case for ES5 as well ?

Comment: Yes, it's also the case when a modern engine interprets ES5 - it makes no difference that the code is not using ES6+ features.

Comment: @Bergi No, I mean is it as efficient in IE? Since OP is striving for efficiency, its likely they also want full browser compatibility.

Comment: Dunno, one would have to benchmark it. (Personally I don't care about IE). Afaik Chakra has been pretty good at this stuff too. Of course in older engines there might have been a difference, on the other hand, in even older engines there simply was no `.filter` and you had to polyfill it anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Updated the answer, do you think I could further improve it?

Comment: It's ok, although I'd just have dropped the entire paragraph instead of adding an extra explanation :-)

Comment: It is for node.js 8+, not for browser.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back In that case you can ignore what I said about the for loops, efficiency wise they are the same